# get values from asynchronous callback

Tags: javascript

Hello am trying to get the location for each loop. Yahoo placemaker is used to get locations from text variables of an array.Within each loop am sending the location to an outer function but I am not getting the values. Does anyone know what am doing wrong? Thanks!

```
    function replace_undefined(array, text_array) {
        console.log(text_array);
        for (i = 0, l = text_array.length; i < l; i++) {
            var text = array[i].text;
            Placemaker.getPlaces(text, function (o) {
                console.log(o);
                if ($.isArray(o.match)) {
                    if (o.match[0].place.name == "Europe" || o.match[0].place.name == "United States") {
                        var location = o.match[1].place.name;
                        getLocation(location);
                    }
                    if ($.isArray(o.match)) {
                        if (o.match[0].place.name !== "Europe") {
                            var location = o.match[0].place.name;
                            getLocation(location);
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (!$.isArray(o.match) && o.error == "no locations found") {
                    var location = "";
                    getLocation(location);

                }
                if (!$.isArray(o.match) && o.error !== "no locations found") {
                    var location = o.match.place.name;
                    getLocation(location);
                }
            });
        }

        function getLocation(n) {
            return function () {
                console.log('Location: ' + n);
            };
        }


    }
```

Comment: I don't have the time needed to help you further, but you know that you're using [strict (un)equality](http://jonkruger.com/blog/2009/04/07/strict-equality-triple-equals-operators-in-javascript/) here `!==`, isn't?

Comment: yes i know that @MarceloAssis

Answer (score 0):

Your question doesn't exactly say where the problem lies; I'm assuming it is in the calls to `getLocation`.

One thing I noticed immediately is that `getLocation` returns a function, so simply doing `getLocation(location);` is not going to do anything other than return that function. You will need to do `(getLocation(location))();` to actually call the function that is returned by `getLocation()`.

Is there a reason that you're returning a function from `getLocation`?

Comment: Am actually trying to store the locations back to the corresponding user of the an array but i dont know exactly how to do it.

Comment: function getLocation(location) {
      
          return function() {
             loc.push(location);
       console.log(loc);
          };
       } Is there any other way of replacing those values without creating an array each time in the function @Vivin Paliath ? cheers